# Segmentation fault in last iteration of for loop

Tags: c, for-loop, segmentation-fault

I am writing some code that calculates the final grade of a student given the grades and weights for each component. I am running into a segmentation fault when the following for loop is supposed to exit.

```
for (i = 0; i < course.numOfSchemes; i++){
printf("Marking scheme# %u \n", i);
    for (j = 0; j < course.numOfComponents; j++){
        printf("  Enter %s weight: ",course.components[j]);
        scanf("%f", &course.weights[i][j]);
    }
    printf("End: %u \n \n",i);
}
printf("rrr");
```

So, supposing course.numOfSchemes = 2 and course.numOfComponents = 3, this is what a trial run would look like. You'll notice that The loop goes from beginning to end twice, but the text "rrr" never gets printed. Therefore, I am assuming the fault happens during the check that happens when the loop is trying to quit.

```
Marking scheme# 0 
  Enter A weight: 20
  Enter B weight: 30
  Enter C weight: 50
End: 0 

Marking scheme# 1 
  Enter A weight: 40
  Enter B weight: 40
  Enter C weight: 20
End: 1 

Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

Comment: try `printf("rrr\n");`

Comment: And if you do as @BLUEPIXY suggests, you will probably find that your segfault in fact occurs later.  `stdout` is normally line buffered, and the buffer is not normally flushed when the program terminates abruptly.

Comment: Is `course.weights` an array of type `float`?

Comment: Can you show us your full code, especially the declaration of the structure for course?  Also, as John Bollinger points out that stdout is line-buffered, stderr is not, so you can use `fprintf(stderr, "rrr\n")` in place of what Bluepixy suggested.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`printf()` doesn't flush after the call unless you have a newline character in your format string. It's likely, that you have some other code after `printf()` that causes a buffer overrun, like this:

```
printf("printed\n");
printf("not printed");
char a[1];
for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
{
    a[i] = 0xff;
}
```

So output of this sample will be like that:

```
printed 
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

Comment: Thanks! I was going crazy!